# how can i get google authentications to work with react.js, firebase, redux?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-redux, google-oauth

I'm trying to get google authentication to work with firebase and redux and the program compiles but the google authentication won`t work
This is my code:

firebase.js

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
import 'firebase/compat/storage';

export const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: ""
  };

  const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
  const auth = firebase.auth();
  const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
  const storage = firebase.storage();

  export { auth, provider, storage};
  export default db;
```

store index.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import  ThunkMiddleware  from "redux-thunk";
import rootReducer from "../reducers";

export const store = createStore( rootReducer, applyMiddleware(ThunkMiddleware));

export default store;
```

action index.js

```
import { auth, provider } from "../firebase";

export function signInAPI() {
    return (dispatch) => {
        auth 
        .signInWithPopup(provider)
        .then((payload) => {
            console.log(payload);
        })
        .catch((error) => alert(error.message));
    };
}
```

login.jsx

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { signInAPI } from "../actions";

export const Login = (props) => {
    return (
        <Container>
            <Section> 
                <Form>
                    <Google onClick={() => props.signIn}>
                        <img src="/images/google.svg" alt="" />
                        Sign in with Google
                    </Google>
                </Form>
            </Section>
        </Container>
    );
};


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return{};
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    signIn: () => dispatch(signInAPI()),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login);
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "./store";
 
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
 
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
       <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

I might also add that I have the latest version of everything as well so do anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: Is there an error in your browser console?

Comment: I know you might have already done this but you didn't include it in the code above. Make sure you didn't forget to wrap your app with `Provider` from `import { Provider } from 'react-redux'` and you passed `store` as here https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started#provider

Comment: Try import 'firebase/storage';